# How can we improve the [disaster] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [disaster](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster) and it's got a couple questions on it. Most are about planning for a disaster, but then there's one where it's used because I'm assuming the asker believed the situation to be a disaster.

I can understand why it got used that way. a tag for [disaster](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster) is used for questions about disasters. But we really don't want people using this tag all willy-nilly on questions they think are disaster situations. [Which is also the reason why we don't have a tag for emergencies](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/676/so-i-created-the-emergency-tag-today).

Is there something we can do to improve this tag so that it's clear to new users what questions are supposed to be tagged with it?

If it's really just about being prepared for an emergency, how about we rename it to [emergency-preparedness](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-preparedness) or [emergency-preparation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-preparation)?

Comment: I just removed an inappropriate use of the disaster tag.  Probably the one (cat ate a half-eaten rabbit) that refers to the initial situational "disaster situation".

Answer (score 4):

I support renaming [disaster](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster) to [emergency-preparedness](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-preparedness) or [emergency-preparation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-preparation)

Comment: I vote [tag:emergency-preparedness] over [tag:emergency-preparation], which should actually be [tag:emergency-preparations] because PLURAL.

Comment: Also, make sure it synonyms with [tag:disaster], if renaming doesn't automatically do that.